# Parsing JSON object from service call Spring JAVA

Tags: java, json, spring

I am getting the following response from some service call . I am trying to parse the JSON . I am actually new to JAVA and not sure about how to parse JSON objects returned from HTTP call . I am getting the following error :

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array.
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:197) ~[json-20180813.jar!/:na]
```

Code :

```
            Object resp = hiveApiClient.getEnrollmentSearchDetails(certificate, employeeId);
            logger.info("response : " + resp);
             JSONArray mainArray = new JSONArray(resp);

             // The nested array is at the second position : 1
             JSONArray nestedArray = mainArray.getJSONArray(1);

             // the interesting main JSONObject is on the first position 
             // of the nested array : 0
             JSONObject interestingJSONObject = nestedArray.getJSONObject(0);
             logger.info("XXX :{}", interestingJSONObject);
             String courseId = interestingJSONObject.getJSONObject("additionalData").getString("courseId");
             logger.info("XXXX :{}",courseId);
            return courseId;
```

Response :

```
[
    "list", [{
        "@type": "com.saba.services.calendar.CalendarElementDetail",
        "eventType": "ILTCLASS",
        "elementName": "Microservice Application Architecture",
        "elementId": "class000000000013497",
        "eventId": "timel000000000103609",
        "ownerID": "emplo000000000096641",
        "locationId": "locat000000000003165",
        "locationName": "IND-Bangalore-Karnataka",
        "additionalData": {
            "@type": "map",
            "locationTimeZone": "tzone000000000000042",
            "eventID": "class000000000013497",
            "locationName": "IND-Bangalore-Karnataka",
            "locationId": "locat000000000003165",
            "transcriptID": "ofapr000000002962367",
            "registrationID": "regdw000000001766254",
            "eventName": "Microservice Application Architecture",
            "moduleID": "regmd000000002147176",
            "courseID": "cours000000000031995"
        },
        "startDate": {
            "@type": "com.saba.customtypes.DateWithLocale",
            "date": 1538613000000,
            "locale": "03-OCT-2018",
            "timeInLocale": "8:30 PM",
            "dateInUserTimeZone": "03-OCT-2018",
            "timeInUserTimeZone": "5:30 PM",
            "dateInCustomTimeZone": null,
            "timeInCustomTimeZone": null,
            "customTimeZoneDate": 0,
            "timeInStandardFormat": "8:30 PM",
            "dateInStandardFormat": "10/03/2018"
        }
    }]
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to"? That's very vague.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all, your json is not valid because of this}:

```
["list" : /* something here but anyway, not the concern here */ ]
```

when it should have been

```
{"list" : /* something here but anyway not the concern here */}
```

I think your problem is with the understanding of how a JSON file works and what is a json object and a json array. Please correct your JSON input so that we can provide you with insights on how to retrieve the value you need.

Additionally, I would recommend you looking into [Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) lib for parsing JSON objects to JAVA POJOs directly really easily. The link is a great tutorial to get you started here. Furthermore, jackson is already included with Spring so that you literally have nothing to install.

### Edit

I misread the JSON input : I saw a `:` after `"list"` instead of a `,`.

So your JSON is a proper JSON but its a quite uncommon JSON as it is loosely typed and therefore cannot be that easily parsed with standard Jackson library for example. In fact, in the main array, a string is put together with a Json Object which is a very bad practice but that's not your fault as I suppose you are not responsible for the output of this HTTP call.

So how can you actually get your value ? Well let's describe the JSON, you've got here : a JSON array containing a String and another sub JSON array. You want to take some values from the very first JSON object inside the nested json array.

This one :

```
 {
    "@type": "com.saba.services.calendar.CalendarElementDetail",
    "eventType": "ILTCLASS",
    "elementName": "Microservice Application Architecture",
    "elementId": "class000000000013497",
    "eventId": "timel000000000103609",
    "ownerID": "emplo000000000096641",
    "locationId": "locat000000000003165",
    "locationName": "IND-Bangalore-Karnataka",
    "additionalData": {
        "@type": "map",
        "locationTimeZone": "tzone000000000000042",
        "eventID": "class000000000013497",
        "locationName": "IND-Bangalore-Karnataka",
        "locationId": "locat000000000003165",
        "transcriptID": "ofapr000000002962367",
        "registrationID": "regdw000000001766254",
        "eventName": "Microservice Application Architecture",
        "moduleID": "regmd000000002147176",
        "courseID": "cours000000000031995"
    },
    "startDate": {
        "@type": "com.saba.customtypes.DateWithLocale",
        "date": 1538613000000,
        "locale": "03-OCT-2018",
        "timeInLocale": "8:30 PM",
        "dateInUserTimeZone": "03-OCT-2018",
        "timeInUserTimeZone": "5:30 PM",
        "dateInCustomTimeZone": null,
        "timeInCustomTimeZone": null,
        "customTimeZoneDate": 0,
        "timeInStandardFormat": "8:30 PM",
        "dateInStandardFormat": "10/03/2018"
    }
}
```

The first task here is to gather this object. Let's suppose the nested json array is always in the second position after the string and that the JSON object you want is always at the first position of the nested array which might not be the case depending on your input JSON but this was not precised in your question.

```
 JSONArray mainArray = new JSONArray(resp);

 // The nested array is at the second position : 1
 JSONArray nestedArray = mainArray.getJSONArray(1);

 // the interesting main JSONObject is on the first position 
 // of the nested array : 0
 JSONObject interestingJSONObject = nestedArray.getJSONObject(0);
```

So now we want "courseId" from "additionnalData" Json Object :

```
String courseId = interestingJSONObject.getJSONObject("additionalData").getString("courseId");
```

And there you go!

Comment: Thats why I am facing issue . I am getting this response from service call , I just need to fetch couseId from additionalData

Comment: Sure but please update your JSON input so that we can help you out with this!

Comment: I am getting error : 
org.json.JSONException: JSONArray initial value should be a string or collection or array.

Comment: Please update your original post with the full stacktrace

Comment: @AbhishekAnand it's basically saying that the input response is not a JSON array as the one you submitted. Could you please check that the response of the HTTP call gives you this JSON response you put in your question? Just do a `System.out.println(resp)` before the ` new JSONArray(resp)` please.